# I'm getting this error during connecting mongoose to nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am New in Nodejs. I have just started learning about MongoDB and I am trying to host my nodejs application locally via MongoDB Server 6.0 (without using mongoose or atlas).

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/e-commerce')
```

And I am getting this error.

```
D:\Ecommerce-Dashboard\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:755
err = new ServerSelectionError();
      ^
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (D:\Ecommerce-Dashboard\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:755:11)   
    at NativeConnection.openUri (D:\Ecommerce-Dashboard\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:730:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 606629,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (D:\Ecommerce-Dashboard\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:383:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Ecommerce-Dashboard\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:307:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

help to solve this error i am getting this error during connecting mongodb with node js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to file manager and 1st stop and then start MongoDB

[image]

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/e-commerce')
```

try it. Your nodejs app successfully connect to MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you already have a server running on port 27017. You probably got the mongoose server connected while experimenting and didn't close it. The way to solve this is:

1. first put code in that closes the connection on ending the node app. To save you repeating step 2.
2. to close this current connection look at the existing netstat and kill the task.

## In windows its:

- netstat -aon | findstr 27017

*Take the task id (example 12345) then kill it with.*

- taskkill -f -pid 12345

## For unix its:

- netstat -tulpn | grep :27018
- kill -9 12345

Now try running your app again.